# RMagick - S3 - Heroku, problems with RMagick file open

Tags: ruby, imagemagick, sinatra, rmagick, padrino

I am trying to upload a file from browser, then make one thumbnail from it, then upload both to s3.

```
 File.open(params[:file][:tempfile]) do |p|
      AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
          :access_key_id     => settings.s3_key,
          :secret_access_key => settings.s3_secret)
      AWS::S3::S3Object.store(pic_name,p,settings.bucket,:access => :public_read)

      thumb = Magick::Image.read(p)
      thumb.crop_resized!(75, 75, Magick::NorthGravity)

      AWS::S3::Base.establish_connection!(
          :access_key_id     => settings.s3_key,
          :secret_access_key => settings.s3_secret)
      AWS::S3::S3Object.store(pic_name + "s",thumb,settings.bucket,:access => :public_read)
```

I have tried most of the possible code combinations to make it work, but it gives me a segmentation error

```
c:0060 p:---- s:0261 b:0261 l:000260 d:000260 CFUNC  :read
c:0059 p:0117 s:0257 b:0257 l:002638 d:000256 BLOCK  /Users/gkay/Documents/yirmiyedi/web/banne/app/controllers/firsat.rb:33
c:0058 p:---- s:0253 b:0253 l:000252 d:000252 FINISH
c:0057 p:---- s:0251 b:0251 l:000250 d:000250 CFUNC  :open
c:0056 p:0190 s:0247 b:0247 l:002638 d:000246 LAMBDA /Users/gkay/Documents/yirmiyedi/web/banne/app/controllers/firsat.rb:27
```

So it starts when RMagic tries to open the file. I have tried many stuff like

```
thumb = Magick::Image.read(p).first or [0] etc but none of them worked.
```

Any ideas?
params[:file] is the post param which keeps the file

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'd suggest using [Mini Magick](https://github.com/probablycorey/mini_magick) instead - it uses a lot less memory and it's much less buggy. We've had a lot of problems with RMagick, but none with mini magick. And switching from one to the other is very easy.

Comment: Yes, it does. We're using it on several projects deployed on Heroku.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding

```
GC.start
```

At top of your code

Answer (score 0):

The problem solved when i uninstalled the imagemagick, uninstalled rmagick gem, installed imagemagick without openmp, then installed rmagick gem again.

Comment: That's an OSX specific build problem for ImageMagick as far as know. It shouldn't affect a heroku deployment.

Comment: i thought so, started to hate from my mac

Answer (score 0):

For any newer visitors, ImageMagick currently works on Heroku without RMagick, so no need to include  it in your gemfile.

However, if you're using Paperclip, you'll need to specify `gem 'cocaine', '0.3.2'`, as noted in this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12762515/paperclip-gem-validation-error-filename-is-not-recognized-by-the-identify), as some other versions do not work.